# scrolltop() doesn't work in IE9 at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, browser

**http://jsfiddle.net/QF47A/7/**

```
function onscroll(){
    document.getElementById("fly").style.top=""+ $(document).scrollTop() * 5 +"px";
}
```

Check that out... *sigh*

Not working one bit in IE9... Haven't tested in IE10 yet.
But yes, it works in Chrome, Firefox, and almost every browser under the sun except the damned IE.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but if you are already using jQuery, then why use `document.getElementById`?

Comment: @Mathletics C'mon, his question is pretty obvious from the problem he's outlined. It doesn't work in IE9 and he'd like it to - he's supplied his own code and fiddles. No need to be pedantic.

Comment: Meh, thanks @KyleMuir :) I hate little-minded people aha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen to the `window`'s `scroll` event instead:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    document.getElementById("fly").style.top = $(document).scrollTop() * 5 +"px";
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QF47A/26/)

---

Tested in latest Chrome, Firefox, Opera 15 and IE8. Seems to work fine in any browser, the main issue is that IE does not parse the `body`'s `onscroll` attribute to the `window.onscroll` property as other browsers do. [**Live Test Case**](http://jsfiddle.net/DpEx9/2/show). Test case source:

```
<body onscroll="42;">
```

```
document.body.innerHTML = 'Does ' + (window.onscroll ? '' : '<b>not</b> ') + 
    'parse body onscroll attribute to window.onscroll';
```

---

So assigning the event handler directly to [`window.onscroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll) would also solve the issue, but as you're using jQuery the [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is preferred for event binding. It patches cross-browser inconsistencies and you don't have to worry about overwriting pre-existing handlers.